# Fastboot vs. Adb sideload vs. Custom Recovery?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

I have a device that is an A/B device. I want to flash a custom rom I built from scratch. It's been a while for me and Android has changed a lot.

- Xda says to always use a custom recovery like TWRP.
- Google says to use fastboot flashall
- Some other sites say you can do adb sideload in the normal recovery

What is the difference between all these?

Comment: Please always include the manufacturer and model name of your phone. Just "an A/B device" is very unspecific. Is the device bootloader unlocked? What Google says is only valid for Google phones (not Android in general). There are Android devices that doesn't have bootloader with fastboot at all.

Comment: It's a unknown chinese device. The bootlocker is unlockable. It has fastboot and fully treble compliant